# pfgplots: axis with empty range

Tags: pgfplots

With the following MWE (I want to plot a bar chart with symbolic coordinates using `pgfplots`) I get an error that I have no idea how to fix:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction x)
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    % axis on top,
    axis lines*=left,
    ymajorgrids,
    ybar,
    ymin=0, ymax=2000,
    xtick=data,
    ytick = {0,200,400,600,800,1000,1200,1400,1600,1800},
    bar width=0.1cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.1},
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize,align=right,rotate=90},
    symbolic x coords={jan12,feb12,mar12,apr12,may12,jun12,jul12,aug12,sep12,oct12,nov12,dec12
  jan-13,feb-13,mar-13,apr-13,may-13,jun-13,jul-13,aug-13,sep-13,oct-13,nov-13,dec-13},
    ]
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message is a *warning*, not an error.

To prevent it, provide appropriate values for `xmin`, `xmax`; also, there was a missing comma after `dec12`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    % axis on top,
    axis lines*=left,
    ymajorgrids,
    ybar,
    ymin=0, ymax=2000,
    xmin=jan12, xmax=dec-13,
    xtick=data,
    ytick = {0,200,400,600,800,1000,1200,1400,1600,1800},
    bar width=0.1cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
   enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.1},
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize,align=right,rotate=90},
    symbolic x coords={jan12,feb12,mar12,apr12,may12,jun12,jul12,aug12,sep12,oct12,nov12,dec12,
  jan-13,feb-13,mar-13,apr-13,may-13,jun-13,jul-13,aug-13,sep-13,oct-13,nov-13,dec-13},
    ]
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting plot of the example]

Comment: You are right, it is warning, sorry for that. How do I do to show every value symbolic x coordinate as a tick in the x axis? In your answer I only see 6 values. Thanks!

Comment: @petobens You can use `xtick`, as in    `xtick={jan12,feb12,mar12,apr12,may12,jun12,
    jul12,aug12,sep12,oct12,nov12,dec12,
  jan-13,feb-13,mar-13,apr-13,may-13,
  jun-13,jul-13,aug-13,sep-13,oct-13,nov-13,dec-13},`