draw command doesn't work in axis environment
I have tried to draw an ellipse in the axis environment, but whether I use axis cs or not, and even though there are no warnings, no ellipse is drawn.
This is a mwe:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \draw (axis cs: 0,0) --(axis cs: 1,1);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The result is the same if I remove axis cs:. How can this be possible? Thanks for your help.

I'm not sure why you expect an ellipse to be drawn, but the compiler is warning you You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. You must add e.g. [xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166583/82917

If your pgfplots package is up-to-date, you don't need to prefix your coordinates with axis cs:

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[red] (0,0) ellipse[x radius=1, y radius=0.5];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


